# Adding value in the "nth" node of a linked list

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, insert, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to add a value in the "n-th" node of a linked list. If n = 0, the value will be the head of the list. If n is greater than the length of the list, it will be the last node in the list. Otherwise, n will be inserted in the list. However, my code doesn't work. Below is the function in my code that accesses any input and adjusts the inputted list accordingly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

struct node {
    struct node *next;
    int data;
};

struct node *insert_nth(int n, int value, struct node *head);
struct node *strings_to_list(int len, char *strings[]);
void print_list(struct node *head);

// DO NOT CHANGE THIS MAIN FUNCTION

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int value;
    scanf("%d", &value);
    // create linked list from command line arguments
    struct node *head = NULL;
    if (argc > 1) {
        // list has elements
        head = strings_to_list(argc - 1, &argv[1]);
    }

    struct node *new_head = insert_nth(n, value, head);
    print_list(new_head);

    return 0;
}



// Insert a new node containing value at position n of the linked list.
// if n == 0, node is inserted at start of list
// if n >= length of list, node is appended at end of list
// The head of the new list is returned.
struct node *insert_nth(int n, int value, struct node *head) {
    struct node *temporary = head;
    struct node *p;
    p = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    p->data = value; 
    int count = 0;

    while (temporary != NULL) {
        count++;
        temporary = temporary->next;
    }

    if (n == 0) {
        p->next = head;
        return p;
    }

    else if (n >= count) {
        while (temporary != NULL) {
            temporary = temporary->next;
        }
        temporary->next = p;
        p->next = NULL;
        return head; 
    }

    else {
        int i = 0;
        while (i < count && temporary != NULL) {
        temporary = temporary->next; 
        }
    temporary = p;
    p->next = temporary;
    return head;
    }
}

// DO NOT CHANGE THIS FUNCTION
// create linked list from array of strings
struct node *strings_to_list(int len, char *strings[]) {
    struct node *head = NULL;
    int i = len - 1;
    while (i >= 0) {
        struct node *n = malloc(sizeof (struct node));
        assert(n != NULL);
        n->next = head;
        n->data = atoi(strings[i]);
        head = n;
        i -= 1;
    }   
    return head;
}

// DO NOT CHANGE THIS FUNCTION
// print linked list
void print_list(struct node *head) {
    printf("[");    
    struct node *n = head;
    while (n != NULL) {
        // If you're getting an error here,
        // you have returned an invalid list
        printf("%d", n->data);
        if (n->next != NULL) {
            printf(", ");
        }
        n = n->next;
    }
    printf("]\n");
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide a complete example with a `main` program issuing your `insert_nth` in a way the reproduce your problem? And by the way: when you write "it doesn't work" what do you actually mean? It crashes? It corrupts the data? What?

Comment: I tried to include the whole program, but I couldn't post it because apparently it was too much code. I'll try again though. And what I mean is that it fails most of my practice tests.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to refactor your code like this:

```
struct node *insert_nth(int n, int value, struct node *head) {
    struct node *el;
    struct node *curr = head, *prev = NULL; // current and previous elements

    el = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    el->data = value;

    // Insert in the head
    if (n == 0 || head == NULL) {
        el->next = head;
        return el;
    }

    // Move to second element
    prev = head;
    curr = head->next;
    n--;

    // Iterate until n-th element or the end of the list
    while (curr != NULL && n != 0) {
        prev = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
        n--;
    }

    // Insert between previous and current elements
    prev->next = el;
    el->next = curr;

    return head;
}
```

First of all you need to check if the list is empty or `n` is 0. If not, iterate until the n-th element. I suggest you to use a couple of pointer for current and previous element. Then insert your new element between the previous and current pointers. In the case you are at then end of the list the current pointer will be `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

For starters the order of the parameters of the function should be changed. The first should specify the list that is what is being changed, The second parameter should specify the value that will be inserted in the list and the third parameter should specify the position at which the value will be inserted.

The position should have unsigned int type for example `size_t`. There is no any sense to specify the signed integer type `int` for the position.

To calculate the current number of nodes in the list is totally redundant.After this loop

```
while (temporary != NULL) {
    count++;
    temporary = temporary->next;
}
```

the pointer `temporary` will be equal to `NULL`. So using this pointer in the subsequent loops like in this

```
else {
    int i = 0;
    while (i < count && temporary != NULL) {
    temporary = temporary->next; 
    }
temporary = p;
p->next = temporary;
```

does not make sense and moreover in this loop

```
else if (n >= count) {
    while (temporary != NULL) {
        temporary = temporary->next;
    }
    temporary->next = p;
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

using the pointer results in undefined behavior.

Here is a demonstrative program with several tests.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node 
{
    struct node *next;
    int data;
};

struct node * insert_nth( struct node *head, int value, size_t n )
{
    struct node *new_node = malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );

    new_node->data = value;

    struct node *current = head, *prev = NULL;

    while ( n-- && current != NULL )
    {
        prev = current;
        current = current->next;
    }

    new_node->next = current;

    if ( prev == NULL )
    {
        head = new_node;
    }
    else
    {
        prev->next = new_node;
    }

    return head;
}

// DO NOT CHANGE THIS FUNCTION
// print linked list
void print_list(struct node *head) {
    printf("[");    
    struct node *n = head;
    while (n != NULL) {
        // If you're getting an error here,
        // you have returned an invalid list
        printf("%d", n->data);
        if (n->next != NULL) {
            printf(", ");
        }
        n = n->next;
    }
    printf("]\n");
}

int main(void) 
{
    {   
        struct node *head = NULL;

        head = insert_nth( head, 0, 0 );

        print_list( head );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );

    {   
        struct node *head = NULL;

        head = insert_nth( head, 1, 0 );

        print_list( head );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );

    {   
        struct node *head = NULL;

        head = insert_nth( head, 0, 0 );
        head = insert_nth( head, 1, 1 );

        print_list( head );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );

    {   
        struct node *head = NULL;

        head = insert_nth( head, 1, 1 );
        head = insert_nth( head, 0, 0 );

        print_list( head );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );

    {   
        struct node *head = NULL;

        head = insert_nth( head, 1, 0 );
        head = insert_nth( head, 3, 1 );
        head = insert_nth( head, 2, 1 );
        head = insert_nth( head, 0, 0 );
        head = insert_nth( head, 4, 10 );

        print_list( head );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
[0]

[0]

[0, 1]

[0, 1]

[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

The function `insert` can be more safer and simpler if to pass the pointer to the head node to the function by reference.

In this case the function can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node 
{
    struct node *next;
    int data;
};

int insert_nth( struct node **head, int value, size_t n )
{
    struct node *new_node = malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
    int success = new_node != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        new_node->data = value;

        while ( *head != NULL && n-- )
        {
            head = &( *head )->next;
        }

        new_node->next = *head;
        *head = new_node;
    }

    return success;
}

// DO NOT CHANGE THIS FUNCTION
// print linked list
void print_list(struct node *head) {
    printf("[");    
    struct node *n = head;
    while (n != NULL) {
        // If you're getting an error here,
        // you have returned an invalid list
        printf("%d", n->data);
        if (n->next != NULL) {
            printf(", ");
        }
        n = n->next;
    }
    printf("]\n");
}

int main(void) 
{
    {   
        struct node *head = NULL;

        insert_nth( &head, 0, 0 );

        print_list( head );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );

    {   
        struct node *head = NULL;

        insert_nth( &head, 1, 0 );

        print_list( head );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );

    {   
        struct node *head = NULL;

        insert_nth( &head, 0, 0 );
        insert_nth( &head, 1, 1 );

        print_list( head );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );

    {   
        struct node *head = NULL;

        insert_nth( &head, 1, 1 );
        insert_nth( &head, 0, 0 );

        print_list( head );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );

    {   
        struct node *head = NULL;

        insert_nth( &head, 1, 0 );
        insert_nth( &head, 3, 1 );
        insert_nth( &head, 2, 1 );
        insert_nth( &head, 0, 0 );
        insert_nth( &head, 4, 10 );

        print_list( head );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is the same as shown above

```
[0]

[1]

[0, 1]

[0, 1]

[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Pay attention to that the parameter of the function `print_list` should be declared with the qualifier const because the list is not changed in the function.

```
void print_list( const struct node *head );
```